# How to get header data of postman using gin package in golang

Tags: go, postman, go-gin

I want to get the `header` data using `gin` package(golang) in the **postman** but I don't get any idea how to do it. I search it for google but not getting any answer. Can anyone help me to get the data from the **postman** `header` the data I want to get is shown in image.

Image:-
[image]

Comment: ```c.GetHeader("token")```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the token header with `c.Request.Header["Token"]`.
Here is a sample code.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "token_data": c.Request.Header["Token"],
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

Here is an example screenshot of postman.
[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: sir @ShivaKishore can we change this data into string?

Comment: Here the token is an header. it is defined in go as `type Header map[string][]string` so for `c.Request.Header["Token"]` you will get an array of `string`. if you always send a single value to the token you can access it by `c.Request.Header["Token"][0]`, this will return a string.

Answer (score 5):

I use this code and work well

```
  func getProduct(c *gin.Context) {
        token := strings.Split(c.Request.Header["Authorization"][0], " ")[1]
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"result": "get product", "token": token})
    }
```

---

Here is the test data

GET http://localhost:8081/api/v2/product HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg4OTI4NzY0LCJleHAiOjE1ODg5MzM3NjR9.GrPK-7uEsfpdAYamoqaDFclYwTZ3LOlspoEXUORfSuY

Answer (score 5):

Instead of accessing request object directly, gin provides a getter (easier to use and makes code cleaner). Based on @Shiva accepted answer:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            // or c.GetHeader("Authorization")
            "token_data": c.GetHeader("Token"),
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

Comment: Much more elegant solution.